# CORS policy blocks XMLHttpRequest

Tags: django, angular, xmlhttprequest, localhost, django-cors-headers

With Ionic Angular running in on my localhost I made this call to my Django backend (running on different localhost):

```
  test() {
    return this.httpClient.get(endpoint + '/test', {
      headers: { mode: 'no-cors' },
    });
  }
```

And on the backend side I have following code to respond:

```
@csrf_exempt
def test(request):
  response = json.dumps({'success': True})
  return HttpResponse(response, content_type='application/json', headers={'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'})
```

I have also this in my settings.py file:

```
 INSTALLED_APPS = [
      ...
      'corsheaders',

    ]

    MIDDLEWARE = [
      ...
      'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
     ]

     CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True 
     CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
```

Still, I get this error message in my console:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/test' from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field mode is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to just add one more setting

```
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_HEADERS=True
```

Other than the above you do not need to set a header on each response. Just simply respond back with payload as

```
@csrf_exempt
def test(request):
  response = json.dumps({'success': True})
  return HttpResponse(response, content_type='application/json', headers={'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'})
```